# Trigonometric fraction Inequality question

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Let

> $$ 1< \alpha_1<\alpha_2<......<\alpha_n< \pi/2$$ then prove that $$ tan(\alpha_1)< \frac{sin(\alpha_1)+sin(\alpha_2)+.....+sin(\alpha_n)}{cos(\alpha_1)+cos(\alpha_2)+......+cos(\alpha_n)} < tan(\alpha_n)$$

I tried to solve the problem but I am not actually able to get a well established answer or you can say I am not even able to advance ahead to solve this one. It tried to use AM-GM inequality, but its didn't work as I couldn't establish any direct relation.

Comment: It's easy, $\sin(x)$ function is ascending on the given interval, while $\cos(x)$ is descending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $\sin(x)$ [is ascending](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(x)) function on the given interval: 
$$n\cdot \sin(\alpha_1) < \sin(\alpha_1) + ... + \sin(\alpha_n) < n\cdot \sin(\alpha_n)$$

Because $\cos(x)$ [is descending](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(x)) function on the given interval: 
$$n\cdot \cos(\alpha_1) > \cos(\alpha_1) + ... + \cos(\alpha_n) > n\cdot \cos(\alpha_n)$$

Or:
$$\frac{1}{n\cdot \cos(\alpha_1)} < \frac{1}{\cos(\alpha_1) + ... + \cos(\alpha_n)} < \frac{1}{n\cdot \cos(\alpha_n)}$$

All positive values. That's pretty much it.