# Trigonometric Inequality including n terms of sine and cosine

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I just came across this:

[image]

I would appreciate anyone's help.
Thanks!

Edit: Duplicate exists ([Trigonometric fraction Inequality question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812003/trigonometric-fraction-inequality-question))
Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent is strictly increasing and the cosine positive on the interval $(0, \frac \pi 2)$,
therefore for each $k$
$$
 \sin \alpha_k = \tan \alpha_k \cdot \cos \alpha_k < \tan \alpha_n \cdot \cos \alpha_k
$$
Adding these inequalities gives the right inequality. The left one is
obtained similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Because if $0<x<y$ and $a>b>0$ then
$$\frac{x}{a}<\frac{x+y}{a+b}<\frac{y}{b}$$